# What's a good Clifford+T circuit for a controlled-controlled-SWAP gate?

Tags: circuit-construction, clifford-group

[Mosca and Mukhopadhyay](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.12440) give a Clifford+T circuit for a three-qubit Fredkin (controlled-SWAP) gate:

[image: Clifford+T for Fredkin]

This uses four $T$ and three $T^\dagger$ gates at a T-depth of four.

What would the T-count and depth be for a four-qubit C***C***SWAP gate, e.g., a controlled-***controlled***-SWAP Gate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a [CCSWAP out of 6 T gates](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%7Ehhqv%22%2C%22%7Ehhqv%22%2C%22%7Ehhqv%22%2C%22%7Ehhqv%22%2C1%2C%22%7Ehhqv%22%2C%22%7Ehhqv%22%2C%22%7Ehhqv%22%2C%22%7Ehhqv%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%7Ereka%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22X%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%2C%22X%5E-%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Measure%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22X%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%7Ea48c%22%2C%22%7Ea48c%22%2C%22%7Ea48c%22%2C%22%7Ea48c%22%2C1%2C%22%7Ea48c%22%2C%22%7Ea48c%22%2C%22%7Ea48c%22%2C%22%7Ea48c%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22Swap%22%2C%22Swap%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%5D%2C%22gates%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Ea48c%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22verify%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Ehhqv%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Ereka%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22%7C0%3E%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%22%7D%5D%7D):

[image]

The reaction depth of this construction is 2.
All the T gates apply to observables that commute, and so they can be performed in parallel using ancilla qubits, which is the first reaction.
The second reaction is the feedback CZ and CX, which can't be done until the measurement affected by the T gates resolves.
This circuit is derived from the CCCZ in [arXiv:2106.11513](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.11513).

The construction you gave for the CSWAP is unnecessarily expensive. The actual T cost should be 4 not 7 and the actual reaction depth should be 2 not 3. Conjugate the CCX from [arXiv:1212.5069](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5069) or [arXiv:1709.06648](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.06648) by CNOTs and you get a CSWAP.